# How to use notification for Ionic app?

Tags: android, notifications, ionic-framework

I have build an app that use a json file from a server and show the data to users.Data update on daily base on the server and every day has a file which i used to served the data to view.I build the apk file and install it on android phone and it is working properly.

Now i want to send a notification(message,alert) to user when data is updated on server so that user can see the new data.I want some brief description.

Thanks.

Comment: can you able to describe more what you are looking for ? are you looking some to create a notification when your app is not used ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ionic is only for UI, if you use phonegap/cordova structure then use pushplugin for notification
find pushplugin on github here..

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

ionic.io pushPlugin is an option, but you can do that with a couple of couchDb-PouchDb syncronized. 
pouchDb provide a very simplest change Api. 
indeed ionic is a Saas/pay services.